# Variations of "Ich kann es nicht ertragen."

Tags: english-to-german, phrase, slang, teen-slang

I am using the internet, dictionaries (Pons, Duden, Langenscheidt) und various automatic translation services to improve my German. Sometimes there seems to be only one German phrase for multiple English thoughts.

The German phrase, **Ich kann es nicht ertragen**, seems to be the only way that a person can express the following English sentences.

- I can't bear it. (the weight of it is too much)
- I can't stomach it. (it causes my stomach to feel pain)
- I can't tolerate it. (it makes me suffer)
- I can't stand it. (it makes it impossible to stand)
- I can't endure it. (the duration is too long)
- I can't take it. (it is too much for me)

Are there other ways to express, **Ich kann es nicht ertragen**, other than this one way? Are there more variations that people would use in slang, more common language. Are there finer ways to express this thought that have more flare and color to them?

Can the following phrases be used as substitutes:

- Ich kann nicht damit umgehen.
- Ich kann nicht damit leben.

If this is an inappropriate question for this forum, try not to totally destroy me. Ich kannte es nicht ertragen. :)

Comment: Hint: if the negation particle *nicht* negates a whole sentence, it comes at the very end of it (as in *ich ertrage es **nicht***). If the sentence has a multi-part predicate (*mehrteiliges Prädikat*), the negation word comes directly before the second part (as in *ich kann es **nicht ertragen***). That means: *Ich kann damit **nicht umgehen*** and *ich kann damit **nicht leben***. Furthermore, the *Konjunktiv II* of *ich kann* is *ich k**ö**nnte*.

Comment: I took a stab at this and got bogged down because I'm not sure of the scope. If you're looking alternate ways of translating this sentence then I think a) there are too many to list and b) asking for translations is discouraged here. Natural languages always offer multiple ways of expressing the same thought, but that seems off-topic here because it's not about German in particular. The short answer to all four parts is *yes* excepting the comment by @amadeusamadeus. It might be better to instead focus on the single word *ertragen* and ask if there are synonyms and when you would use them.

Comment: Your first interpretation (*the weight of it is too much*, speaking about physical weight) is not a meaning of ***Ich kann es nicht ertragen*** in German. Physical ability (or the lack thereof) to carry something could however be expressed through ***Ich kann es nicht tragen***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. *Ich krieg' zu viel!* is a a humerous exclamation of despair: *Jetzt funktioniert der Drucker schon wieder nicht, ich krieg hier noch mal zuviel!*
2. *etwas wird mir zu viel* can refer to anything that exceeds the speaker's tolerance threshold (there is too much noise, there are too many telephone calls in too short time, too many tasks to fulfil for my forces ...): *Ich muss mit dem Fitnessstudio aufhören, das wird mir langsam alles zu viel mit dem Freizeitstress.*
3. *Bauchschmerzen bei etwas haben* = to feel uncomfortable / to have concerns when doing something: *Ich muss ihm endlich sagen, dass ich seinen Vorschlag nicht gut finde, aber ich habe Bauchschmerzen dabei, denn er hat sehr viel Arbeit darin investiert.*
4. *etwas nicht mehr hören können* = to be sick of hearing an argument or an (often heard) exuse: *Ich kann diese ewigen Corona-Sendungen im Radio nicht mehr hören.*
5. *etwas / jemanden nicht länger ertragen können* is an expression saying: I'm not willing to tolerate these uncomfortable  circumstances or an annoying person around me any longer: *Ich ertrage diesen Kerl nicht länger. Entweder, ihr versetzt mich in eine andere Abteilung oder ich kündige.*
6. *etwas nicht länger aushalten* can mean: I urgently should take action in order to put an end to my unbearable situation: *Ich halte diesen ständigen Lärm von der Baustelle nicht länger aus. Wenn sich da nichts tut, muss ich umziehen oder ins Hotel gehen.*
7. *nicht mit etwas leben können*: I rather use it positively: *ich kann damit leben* = for me it's acceptable, but far from being the best solution: *Okay, mein Chef ist ein Choleriker, aber ich kann damit leben, mit ihm habe ich wenig zu tun, und die Kollegen sind ganz nett.*
8. *jemand kann etwas nicht haben* means: the person is disturbed or annoyed by something another person is doing: *Stell diese Musik ab! Du weißt doch, dass Opa die nicht haben (/ leiden) kann. | Viele Kinder können es nicht haben, wenn die Eltern bei ihnen minutenlang die Kleidung zurechtziehen.*

There are many more colloquial expressions one can use in similar situations:

- jemandem (mit etwas) auf die Nerven gehen
- jemandem reißt der Geduldsfaden
- jemand ist mit seiner Geduld am Ende
- jemandem reißt die Hutschnur
- jemandem reicht es
- etwas leid sein
- jemandem steht es bis Oberkante Unterlippe
- jemand hat die Faxen dicke (mit)
- drei Kreuze machen, wenn etwas vorbei ist
- bedient sein
- kurz vorm Durchdrehen sein
- (bald) im Sechseck (/ -Dreieck) springen
- etwas nicht mehr länger mitmachen (wollen)
- sich etwas nicht mehr länger reintun (/ reinziehen)
- jemandem wird etwas zu bunt
- jemandem wird etwas zu blöd
- das ist mir alles zu dumm (/ zu stressig / zu wischi-waschi / zu unprofessionell hier / zu kindergartenmäßig ...)
- nichts wie weg hier! nichts wie raus hier!

...

Comment: Never encountered "_Ich krieg' zu viel!_" in any German language. Why not the very common "_Mir langt's!_"?

Comment: @AmigoJack: Natürlich passt auch _mir langt's, echt jetzt!_, ebenso wie _mir reicht's, ich hab jetzt langsam den Kaffee auf , mir steht's bis hier, ich kann nicht mehr ich will nicht mehr, ich krieg die Krise, ich werd zum Elch!, ich bin's sowas von leid, ich hab's satt, ich kuck mir das nicht mehr lange an, genug ist genug, für mich war's das jetzt, Ende aus Mickymaus_ - kannst es gerne ergänzen, da kommt so schnell kein Ende ... Und: Jeder kann nur aus der Regionalsprache heraus 'colloquial' (so war die Frage) sprechen, die er auch kennt..

Comment: @AmigoJack: I know *zu viel kriegen*; it is also in [OpenThesaurus](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/zu%20viel%20kriegen).

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of a few additions to Ralf Joerres' very comprehensive answer:

- *mir langt's*, colloquial, southern German alternative for *mir reicht's*: "I've had enough of this". Also, *es langt jetzt*, "enough is enough".
- *ich hab die Schnauze voll*, vulgar, literally, "my snout is full": "I'm fed up with this"
- *ich kann das nicht ab*, colloquial, "I strongly dislike this"